# ionic2 how to remove white space from status bar from top in iphone

Tags: iphone, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am working on ionic 2 and here is my local set up as-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

I wanted to remove white space from top in iphone, How I can?

Comment: white space ???

Comment: Yes, White screen which get appear on top (Status Bar).

Comment: can you attach me a screen shot

Comment: I got the solution of the same, Thanks for your time @MohanGopi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to say that I got my task done with this answer, I am really thankful for that. I came to see solution [in this article](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-remove-space-at-the-top-of-navbar/44194/9).

1. Open app.ts file and go to bottom
2. Add this line of code as-

---

```
let config = {statusbarPadding: false};
```

as we have taken config as a variable, which we need to get load when app get read, so add this variable as-

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp,null, config);
```

Now the final code will be like this-

```
let config = {statusbarPadding: false};
ionicBootstrap(MyApp,null, config);
```

This worked for me.